# Android - add items to list view programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to create a to do list in android, where each item is a checkbox. I want to be able to programmatically update the list of items as the user (me) adds a new task. Any tips for how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) would be good here is a few design tips:

1. You probably need to create layout with listview
2. Then create another layout for your list rows to inflate which is in
   your case checkbox
3. Create adapter for listview to set items by extending ArrayAdapter.
4. Implement getView method and constructor of adapter class
5. If user add something to list notify adapter that data set has
   changed and update ui accordingly

Note : do not update UI from background thread just use UI thread for this

Note 2 : In lists android have row recycle so when list expend the screen width check if checkboxes hold their states.

Hope it helps.