# Fill ListView from JSON data

Tags: android, json

I want to retrieve data by using Json and set it in listview. when I used textview

```
ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answere);
ans.setText(jsonObject.getString("responses").trim());
```

it was work correctly but when I used listview it did not work!!
picture here show a lot of tries and some of these I put it as a comment. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzCCW.png)
and these are my tries

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                   // String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(jsonObject), "UTF-8");
                   // Log.e("UTF 8",encoded );
                   // list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                   // edit.setText("");
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   // ans.setText(jsonObject.getString("responses").trim());
                   // ans= new String(jsonObject.getString("responses").trim().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                   //last update
                    /*
                    ans=jsonObject.getString("responses").toString().trim();
                    list.add(ans);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);//end of last update */
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                    //List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                        String info = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("responses").trim();
                        list.add(info);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

what is wrong??

Comment: WHAT exaclty is not working? Is it actually being added, do you get exceptions? Is there an error-line, and what could this be? 

It's been a long time since I had to deal with android studio, not sure if it's possible to just add string into a listview. Could be conversion error, could be something else.

Comment: "It did not work" is not a good enough problem description. You need to elaborate on that. Also, please remove the useless code and comments, this site is not a code dump.

Comment: Start with debugging on the .add(info) and check if the 'info' object contains any value (!= null), if this passes with 0 problems try stepping into the setListAdapter(adapter) to encounter any possible exceptions. It is your road to retrieve the error. Good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - add items to list view programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053985/android-add-items-to-list-view-programmatically)